# Can't Overwrite CSV file if Open

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm using powershell to export-csv a table. If the csv file is open anywhere on the network, the script will not overwrite the file. Is there anyway to work around this?

Comment: Save using a different name?  Not sure how else you'd want to handle it if the file is in use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to change how the network deals with users opening the files.
Usually, when a user (who is not an admin) opens a file on the network, you want the user to open it as **read-only**.

Only then, you will be able to overwrite the file using your script (with admin privs ofc)

If you do not have control over the network, the best option would be to create a different file with the same name but with revision number at the end. For example, "a.csv" would become "a001.csv" after the first edit.
Because of the nature of the solution, it will create havoc if multiple users are working on the same file.

In this case, I would suggest looking at version control softwares... But then again, it would be silly to go through all this for just editing a simple .csv file.. So, the answer is "it's complicated"